# Binding Data to server controls in asp:repeater

Tags: data-binding, asprepeater

I would like to have a repeater control bound to method and display the result as a list  of  linkbuttons, but I can't get by head around it. This is what I've tried:

In the asp page I have:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="resultCountRepeater" runat="server" Visible="false" >
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="userResultCount" runat="server" OnClick="userResultCount_Click" Text="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Text") %>" >
                                </asp:LinkButton>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
```

And in the code behind:

```
List<ListItem> resultCountList = new List<ListItem>();
                foreach (ISearchEngine oneEng in engines)
                {
                    ListItem item = new ListItem();
                    item.Text = oneEng.ObectName();
                    item.Value = Convert.ToString(oneEng.PageCount(searchWords, townId));
                    resultCountList.Add(item);
                }
                resultCountRepeater.DataSource = resultCountList;
                resultCountRepeater.DataBind();
```

Unfortunately this is giving me a compile error: The server tag is not well formed.

Any ideas what it wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use single quotes to dynamically set properties.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="userResultCount" runat="server" OnClick="userResultCount_Click" Text="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Text") %>" ></asp:LinkButton>
```

Should be

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="userResultCount" runat="server" OnClick="userResultCount_Click" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Text") %>' ></asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: Thanks that was it. I can't believe I did not see it! You're a life saver.

Comment: No worries! After 10 years of .net dev, that one still gets me every time :D